# Why I cannot see and install the latest version of NeoVim 0.5?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, nvim

I added and updated Debian's experimental distribution to my source list which [should contain neovim 0.5.0-1](https://packages.debian.org/source/experimental/neovim).

`deb http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib non-free`

When I run `apt-cache policy neovim` I can see only 0.4.4-1

```
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.4.4-1
  Version table:
     0.4.4-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
```

If I run `apt-cache policy nano` I can see the latest [version from the experimental](https://packages.debian.org/source/experimental/nano).

```
apt-cache policy nano
nano:
  Installed: 5.4-2
  Candidate: 5.4-2
  Version table:
     5.8-1 1
          1 http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.4-2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll down to the bottom of [the `neovim` package page for `experimental`](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/neovim), you can see that it’s not available on `amd64`. That’s [because it fails to build there](https://buildd.debian.org/status/package.php?p=neovim&suite=experimental) (the build timed out).

A useful tool to figure this out locally is `rmadison`, in the `devscripts` package:

```
$ rmadison neovim
...
neovim     | 0.5.0-1        | experimental            | source, i386, ppc64el
neovim     | 0.5.0-1        | experimental-debug      | source
```

You could add the `i386` architecture with `dpkg --add-architecture i386`, and install that version of the package; or wait for the build to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen. You saved my day!